# Cakephp .xls file attachment through email component

Tags: excel, email, cakephp, attachment, xls

I am working with CakePHP and need to send mail with .xls file attachment.

Although I have tried a lot but didn't get success.

**Note -** FYI, Only PDF files are getting attached with the mails.

Please find my code below -

```
$this->Email->to = 'email address';    
$this->Email->from = 'From email address';
$this->Email->subject = 'Subject'; 
$this->Email->template = 'template name'; 
$Path = TMP;
$fileName = 'testfile.xls';        
$this->Email->filePaths = array($Path);
$this->Email->attachments = array($fileName);                
$this->Email->send();
```

Every time when I execute this code snippet, even mails are receiving but with no attachment.

Comment: which version of cake are you using? that looks like the 1.x syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation ( http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#sending-attachments ) is pretty clear on that.
You need to submit it as an array with the filename as key and the path as array key "file":

```
$email->attachments(array(
    'photo.png' => array(
        'file' => '/full/some_hash.png',
        'mimetype' => 'image/png',
    )
));
```

I dont know where you got your "filePaths" attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your response....
Can you please suggest mimetype for .xls file to use in given code as I have tried with 'application/vnd.ms-excel' but it didn't work while I am getting file attached if I use 'image/png' (which is definitely wrong)?

Comment: cake is not a blackbox ;) looking into the code you should be able to figure out what cake uses internally: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Network/CakeResponse.php#L182 - so either let cake figure it out or set it to  `application/vnd.ms-excel` manually then.